# compilation error "reached end of file while parsing"

Tags: java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cam1 = Camera.open();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if ( isOn ) {
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                cam1.getParameters(params);
                cam1.stopPreview();
                isOn = false;
                btn.setBackground(R.drawable.red_power_button_clip_art_9034);
            } else {
                params = cam1.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                cam1.getParameters(params);
                cam1.stopPreview();
                isOn = true;
                btn.setBackground(R.drawable.green_power_button_clip_art_9023);


            }
```

Comment: you are missing one or more `}`.

Comment: Add a `line-break` with a `}` and again a `line-break` with a `}` and again a `line-break` with a `}`

Comment: I'm sure he just missed to past the closing brackets, else the code would not even compile. You should ask your question in the body text, add the stack trace and also be polite like "Hello" or "Thanks"...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing several closing brackets.

The complete code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cam1 = Camera.open();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if ( isOn ) {
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                cam1.getParameters(params);
                cam1.stopPreview();
                isOn = false;
                btn.setBackground(R.drawable.red_power_button_clip_art_9034);
            } else {
                params = cam1.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                cam1.getParameters(params);
                cam1.stopPreview();
                isOn = true;
                btn.setBackground(R.drawable.green_power_button_clip_art_9023);
            }
       }
   }
}
```